# Linux Mint 20.2 and Virtualenv: activation command ignore me

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, linux-mint, python-venv

So i have this problem and nowhere i can found something like this:

Linux Mint 20.2, Vs Code (but i try also from terminal and is the same).
I had created a virtual environment with classic python3 -m venv env.
Then i try to activate venv with classic source env/bin/activate and i wait that next line in VsCode terminal looks like this:

```
(venv)computer@computer-N750JK:~/Documents/VsCode/Dashboard$....
```

but not... just nothing happen. No errors... no messages... nothing, the same line of code. Like i said, also from terminal is the same!

Anybody had experience on this? Or can show me what mistake do I make?

Thanks ))

Comment: Please don't place answers in your question. Post this as a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE AND SOLVING:**
I try delete env and make new one, this time with command **python -m venv venv** instead of python3 -m venv venv and this time everything work fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).